# How to change the default IP protocol version in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, ip, ipv6, ipv4, default-settings

My web browser—Google Chrome—uses by default `IPv4` even if `IPv6` is available.

How can I change it to use only `IPv6`?

Comment: If you are served a website over IPv4 or IPv6 isn't handled by the browser.

Comment: Which operating system? If Windows, then IPv6 already has the priority (unless you modified the registry).

Comment: Software applications like browsers will not specify the IP protocol version. they leave that up to the OS, because they completely don't care. the details of how the page gets to the browsers IO streams are abstracted away from the application, such that they don't even know which was used.

Comment: Have you tested your browser with https://test-ipv6.com or https://ipv6-test.com?